# Toast inside a Button OnclickListener is not working

Tags: java, android, button, toast

`intdelay` was initialized at the beginning of the code by `1000`.
and I am trying to make sure that `intdelay`'s value is updated by the value in the edit box by adding a toast when the button is clicked.
but when I run the app, I get the following problem:

```
 Error:(46, 22) error: no suitable method found for makeText(<anonymous OnClickListener>,String,int)
method Toast.makeText(Context,CharSequence,int) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; <anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to Context)
method Toast.makeText(Context,int,int) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; <anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to Context)
```

This is the part of my code:

```
  @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        delayedttxt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.delayedttxt);

    String delay=delayedttxt.getText().toString();       //this will get a string
    try{
        int intdelay = Integer.parseInt(delay);
   }catch(NumberFormatException ex){ // handle your exception
    }

    Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            flashLight.switchFlash();
            Toast.makeText(this,"your integer is " + intdelay , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    });
```

How can I solve that?

Comment: debug your code , i think   flashLight.switchFlash(); this have a exception

Comment: easy question!!! everyone is giving answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `makeText` wants to have a `Context` as a first argument. You are inside the `onClick` function of an `OnClickListener`. This means that `this` points to your `OnClickListener`. 
You must have something like this

```
Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this,"your integer is " + intdelay , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 3):

You have given wrong context;
change this line:

```
 Toast.makeText(this,"your integer is " + intdelay , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

to

```
 Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this,"your integer is " + intdelay , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: You can accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
Toast.makeText(YourActivityName.this,"your integer is " + intdelay , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: If it works than accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

Change the context if not somwthing may wrong in flashLight.switchFlash method

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to show your toast inside the `OnClickListener`. The `this` keyword in this case refers to an instance of type `OnClickListener`, and not `Context`, like it is required.

You should use `<YourActivityClass>.this` to refer to the enclosing activity instance, that is a `Context` and can be use to show the toast.

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting this line of code:

```
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"your integer is " + intdelay , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do these in your activity,

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"your integer is " + intdelay , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change from

```
Toast.makeText(this,"your integer is " + intdelay , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

to

```
Toast.makeText(getContext(),"your integer is " + intdelay , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```